# My Custom Liferay Theme looking weird

Tags: liferay-6

I am using Liferay 6.1 with IDE as Eclipse Juno version .

I am having a question with developing new  Theme in Liferay .

I followed the following below steps to do so

1. From IDE , Selected New Liferay Project with name as "Test" and enabled Radio Button Theme
2. Basic Structure for Test-theme got created .
3. Under _diffs folder , i copied 4 folders namely css , images , js and templates as it is
4. deployed it using ant "deploy" option
5. Then finally under Manage -- > Page -->Look and Feel OPtion , selected Test as Theame and saved that

I have represented the above steps in the below screen shot .

[image]

What i was expecting is that the Page should be displayed as same as Classic Theme as  i did not made any
changes to any of the folders (css , images , js , templates) , but unfortunately the is looking weird .

Please see the screen shot the page displayed using Test Theme .

[image]

Answer (score 0):

```
Its look like it is missing css.just extend the classic theme in build.xml
<project name="Fao-theme" basedir="." default="deploy">
    <import file="../build-common-theme.xml" />

    <property name="theme.parent" value="classic" />
</project>
```

check
http://javadispute.com/content/how-add-custom-css-liferay